# Legacy JS bundling & minification with Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, bundle, webpack, bundling-and-minification

My project has multiple JS-Files that contain function declarations without any exporting and uses jquery, jquery-ui and other libraries that need to be accessible globally.
Functions are often called by **inline JavaScript** in html-elements (`<button onclick="doStuff()">...`)

My goal is now to bundle the app files into bundle.js and the vendor files into vendor.js. I've managed to accomplish the second task but the first one is not working as I would have hoped.

The bundle.js file should only contain all .js files concatenated + minified and then be executed in the global context.

What I tried so far:

- **scripts-loader** (no minification...)
- **exports-loader** (context problem?)
- **expose-loader** (doesn't really expose functions globally outside of the bundle and needs exports)

For easier discussion I give a simplified scenario:

### src/a.js

```
function doStuffA() {
    alert("A");
}
```

### src/b.js

```
function doStuffB() {
    alert("B");
}
```

### src/index.js

```
require("script!./a");
require("script!./b");
```

### index.html

```
<body>
    <button onclick="doStuffA()">A</button>
    <button onclick="doStuffB()">B</button>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor.js"></script>
</body>
```

### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.js",
    vendor: [
      "jquery",
      "jquery-ui"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      "jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js', minChunks: Infinity }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to directly attach all this functions to `window`? Like `window.doStuff = function doStuff() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Were you able to figure it out @algorithms?

Comment: @gdad-s-river  Sorry, I am not supporting this system anymore. I ended up using gulp instead of webpack 2 years ago. I'm not sure how the situation is today since Webpack has released quite a few new versions since then.